# Replace the last occurence of a random word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have a little jQuery script that works like Emmet/ZenCoding and that expands keywords to a snippet on the press of the `TAB` key in a `textarea`.

It works fine when there's only one occurence of the keyword, but I don't know how to replace only the last occurence of a word in a string.

Here's an example string that would be typed in the `textarea` :

```
Have a look at the rules : rules
```

In this case, the user would press the `TAB` key after the second rules, and the script fetches the corresponding value in an array, to replace the word with an actual link to the rules. It should (in theory) be replaced by this :

```
Have a look at the rules : http://website.com/rules.php
```

My problem is that I'm using `replace` and it will replace **all** occurences of that word, which is not the desired behavior. Here is the relevant part of the script :

```
var content = $(this).val();
content = content.replace(lastWord, insertSnippets[lastWord]);
$(this).val(content);
```

It first gets the content in the textarea at the time, replace the word (rules) with the corresponding value (the actual link). Is there any way to replace only the last occurence? It won't always be the word "rules", there are a dozen of other keywords of unknown length.

**TL;DR** How  do I replace only the last occurence of a word with jQuery/Javascript?

I was thinking of getting the current position of the caret and replace only the word to its left, but getting the position of the caret seems rather tedious - and I still wouldn't know how to do the replace.

Answer (score 1):

This might do it, so long as your search string doesn't include any regex special characters:

```
var replaceLast = function(searchFor, replaceWith, str) {
    return str.replace(
        new RegExp("^(.*)" + searchFor + "(.*?)$"), 
        function(_, before, after) {return before + replaceWith + after;}
    );
};

replaceLast("rules", "http://website.com/rules.php", 
            "Have a look at the rules : rules", "rules");
//=> "Have a look at the rules : http://website.com/rules.php"
```

If this function were passed to some `curry` function, then you could create a function such as `updateRules` via

```
var updateRules = replaceLast("rules", "http://website.com/rules.php");
// ... later
updateRules("Have a look at the rules : rules", "rules");
//=> "Have a look at the rules : http://website.com/rules.php"
```

But the original function might be all you need.

Comment: This is working very well, the only issue now is that I can only replace one word at the time in the `textarea`. Although this might be because of the way I'm handling all of this, I'll do some more experimenting and try to sort that. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with (only tested webkit) using a `contenteditable` field.

It does a few things nicely, though probably inefficiently:

- Replaces word with a related snippet that live in an object
- replaces only the current word your caret is on
- Sets your cursor to the end of the line after tabbing to complete

Try typing in "blah blah blah rules" and hit tab after "rules". Try it with multiple "rules" in the string.

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content')

content.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

    var _this      = this,
        text       = this.innerHTML;

    if ( event.keyCode == 9 ) {
        event.preventDefault()

        var sel         = window.getSelection(),
            currentWord = getWord(),
            val         = sel.anchorNode.nodeValue,
            snippet     = tabComplete(currentWord),
            range       = sel.getRangeAt(0)

        var selArray    = sel.anchorNode.nodeValue.split(' ')

        if ( snippet !== undefined ) {
            var currentWordPosition = [ (range.endOffset - currentWord.length), range.endOffset ]

            var newText = text.splice(currentWordPosition[0], currentWordPosition[1], ' '+snippet)

            _this.innerHTML = newText;

            sel.collapse(_this.firstChild, sel.anchorNode.nodeValue.length)
        }
    }
  
})

var snippets = {
    'rules' : 'http://website.com/rules.php',
    'faq' : 'http://website.com/faq.php'
}

function tabComplete(string) {

    if ( typeof string !== 'string' ) { return false; }

    var snippetKeys = Object.keys(snippets)

    for ( var i=0; i<snippetKeys.length; i++ ) {
        if ( snippets[string] ) {
            return snippets[string]
        }
    }
}

function getWord() {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    if ( range.collapsed ) {
        text = range.startContainer.textContent.substring(0, range.startOffset+1);
        return text.split(/\b/g).pop();
    }
    return '';
}

String.prototype.splice = function(start, length, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0,start)+replacement+this.substr(start+length);
}
```

```css
#content {
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks a lot for your answer. However, is there a way to make this work with a `textarea` ? I don't have control over the source code of the website I'm using the script on - it's a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex and only match the end of the content string.

```
/yourWord$/
```

will match yourWord if it is at the very end of the string

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I replaced the lastWord var in my code with what you posted, but now it won't expand anymore when I press the `TAB` key.

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak the regex a bit:

```
var content = $(this).val();
content = content.replace(lastWord+'.*?$', insertSnippets[lastWord]);
$(this).val(content);
```

Comment: I tried your code and it won't expand anymore, do I have to do anything to concatenate the lastWord `var` into the regex?

Comment: It still will not work, I did a few `console.log` on "content", "lastWord" and "insertSnippets[lastWord" and I have all the expected values there. It's simply not being replaced. :(